# Connect two custom policies

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have implemented the [custom-mfa-totp](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/custom-mfa-totp) sample. I have defined a custom policy which allows to reset the QR code. Everything works fine.

Now I need to let's say connect the two policies. Let' assume the following scenario:

- User signs up to my B2C
- User signs in, it has to install the authentication app in order to get the verify code
- User is signed in
- Month later the User has to reinstall the app (for an unknown reason). If he goes to the login, a verify code is requested:

[image]

My idea is to add a sort of link in order to open the other policy to reset the QR code. In the documentation I have seen the possibility to add *Action*s, but I have not been able to figure out how.
Any hint?

I already added it:

[image]

But in order to redirect in a right way, i need the parameters from the previous page, such as ´client_Id´ and `redirect_url`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you already know how to [customize the UI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-with-html?pivots=b2c-custom-policy), you can add [ContentDefinitionParameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/relyingparty#contentdefinitionparameters) to your Relying Party policy to pass params to your HTML template. You can use [claim resolvers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/claim-resolver-overview) to get the client_id and redirect_uri:

```xml
<ContentDefinitionParameters>
    <Parameter Name="client_id">{OIDC:ClientId}</Parameter>
    <Parameter Name="redirect_uri">{OIDC:RedirectUri}</Parameter>
</ContentDefinitionParameters>
```

These values can be accessed via JavaScript by parsing the query string from `SETTINGS.remoteResource`. The `SETTINGS` object is injected into your HTML template when the corresponding content definition is loaded by the Identity Experience Framework. Do note that the `SETTINGS` object is part of the internal API and may change between [page layout versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/page-layout).

Now that you have the client_id and redirect_uri, you can generate a link to another policy using JavaScript, although including the original nonce in the policy redirect would probably be a good idea as well.

Comment: I added the params using claim resolvers. I did not find the `SETTINGS` variable youmentioned, but I got the parameters in the URL, in the `diags` parameter.
Thanks!

Comment: @Emaborsa I am on page layout version 2.1.2 and for me the `SETTINGS` object is available in the global scope. You should be able to see it by just typing `SETTINGS` from the browser console.

Comment: ...I found it, but there is no redirectUrl nor clientId.

Comment: There should be a remoteResource property attached to the `SETTINGS` object. The reason why I wouldn't necessarily rely on the `diags` query param is because it looks to me like a kind of diagnostic artifact so I wouldn't trust it to remain consistent across environments. Just guessing though, I don't know how it works exactly.

Answer (score -1):

You can add a link in the custom HTML to `myapp.com/launchPolicyX`. Then the application should make a fresh authentication request using your favorite OpenId library.

Comment: Could you explain me a bit more or give me any samples which help me through?

Comment: Use custom HTML to [brand your page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-with-html?pivots=b2c-user-flow). That allows you to add your own HTML elements (HTML/CSS/JS) to be rendered and merged with the B2C page. In this HTML, embed your own [link](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp) to myapp.com/foo. The /foo endpoint of your app should then trigger a new auth flow with the new policyId.

Comment: OK, but not that easy. In order to start a flow, I need clientId and redirectUrl, which are dyanamic and can differ.

Comment: That’s why your link goes to the app and not directly to the policy.